Database Error in dbt model: Apache Avro failed to read data during dbt build
I'm encountering an issue while running a dbt build command for one of my models in dbt. The error appears during the build process, specifically when reading data from an Avro file, and it's causing the entire build to fail.
Here's the error message I'm seeing:
Database Error in model <model_name> (path/to/model.sql) Error while reading table: <project>.<dataset>.<table>, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to read data with the following error: Invalid operation. Expected: Repeater got SkipStart File: bigstore/<project>/<dataset>/<path>/+0+<file_id>.avro Compiled code at path/to/compiled_model.sql
Additional Context:

This error is specific to one model, and the rest of the models in the project run without issues.
The dbt model in question relies on a table that contains data in Avro format, which seems to be the source of the problem.
The external table, that reads the Avro file contains the Avro data in the correct format.
The error message points to an Avro decoding issue, specifically mentioning "Expected: Repeater got SkipStart." However, I haven't been able to determine the root cause or how to resolve it.
I'm using Google Cloud Storage as a source repo for reading this avro file.

What I’ve tried so far:

I Verified that the table schema and data types match the expectations in my dbt model.
Checked for any version mismatches or issues with the Avro library used.
Reloaded the external table, and the file reads correctly after reloading. When re-running the dbt build, the file imports without issues.
Confirmed the Avro file format is valid by testing it with multiple online converters/validators, all of which read the file correctly.
Cleared dbt's target cache and reran the build, but the issue persists intermittently.

